# Requesting STS Token via SAML with passwords containing special characters

Tags: c#, xml, delphi, sharepoint, saml

**Edit: I noticed that the error does not only occur for the five XML reserved characters, but also for other special characters.**

i have a problem with the SAML request i am using to obtain a STS token.

The SAML request is witten in XML.
If the password sent with the request contains a character that is reserved by XML the login fails. I tried to escape the characters ( & = `&amp;`) or using CDATA

(`lBuilder.Append('<o:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"><![CDATA[').Append(lPassword).Append(']]></o:Password>');`)

but then apparently the password is not recognized correctly and the login still fails. 
If i use CDATA, even the login with a valid password that otherwise works fails. The request is sent via post command to https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf (cDefaultSTS).

Is there a way to correctly escape special characters in passwords without conflicts?
The code is written in Delphi and i am using following client settings to send the post command (lSAMLRequestStream contains the request in XML format).

```
lConnection.Client.Accept := '*/*';
lConnection.Client.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US';
lConnection.Client.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)';
lConnection.Client.ContentType := 'application/soap+xml';
lConnection.Client.HandleRedirects := True;
lConnection.Client.AcceptEncoding := '';
lSTSResponse := lConnection.Post(cDefaultSTS, lSAMLRequestStream);
```

I tried the same in C# using the Microsoft.SharePoint library but the authentication still fails if the password contains one of the reserved characters. Escaping also does not work here.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https:mysite@sharepoint.com"))
{
  var passWord = new SecureString();
  string passwrd = "Password&";

  string encodedXml = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(passwrd);

  foreach (char c in encodedXml.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

  clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@SharePoint.com",passWord);

   Web web = clientContext.Web;
   Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Site);
   clientContext.Load(web);

   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Do you write the xml yourself or are you using a library (like the delphi one using xmlintf/xmldoc). If not, did you use the correct string definition specifiers, like utf-8 and did you use the correct string encoding? ‘HtmlEncode’ it not the same as utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escaping via the CDATA -tag actually was the solution and works. I just had an additional problem with the test account i was using that was making it looks like it still fails because of the password. The c# code bye the way does not require any additional escaping.